# Trying to reverse-convert a vector of time zones

Tags: r, posixct

I have this database of time stamps (AlertTime), and I know what time zone these are in (TimeZone). I know how to set these date to POSIXCT or if they were all UTC, but I'm struggling to get them identified as their local time stamps because most functions don't accept a vector for tz.

I do need both the local time stamp properly formatted (AlertTimeLocal) and the UTC equivalent (AlertTimeUTC).

```
AlertTime               TimeZone                AlertTimeLocal (desired)  AlertTimeUTC (desired)
11 May 2020, 06:22 PM   America/Denver          2020-05-11 18:22:00 MDT   2020-05-12 00:22:00 MDT
11 MAY 2020, 04:11 AM   America/Los_Angeles     2020-05-11 04:11:00 PDT   2020-05-11 11:11:00 UTC
10 MAY 2020, 03:38 PM   America/Chicago         2020-05-10 15:38:00 CDT   2020-05-10 20:38:00 CDT
```

I was using this code but it doesn't seem to do anything anymore:

```
FreshAir$AlertTimeLocal <- mapply(function(x,y) {format(x, tz=y, usetz=TRUE)}, FreshAir$AlertTime, FreshAir$TimeZone)
```

Would a hacky solution be to set all the RAW time stamps to UTC, then convert them to the equivalent time zone in the other direction?

Comment: can you try `force_tzs(dmy_hm(FreshAir$AlertTime), tzones = FreshAir$TimeZone)`

Comment: your column names in the data and the code column names are not matching

Comment: In case you missed my answer-edit, notice that you cannot (easily) have different local time zones within a single column.

Comment: (1) That might be more appropriate as a comment in my answer. (2) I noted in my answer that one cannot have different zones within a single vector. Your answer *depicts* the desired time-of-day but they are not what the OP asked for: the time zone for `AlertTimeLocal` is UTC, not MDT, PDT, and CDT as the OP requested. Granted, it's over to the OP to accept the answer, but what is requested cannot happen (as easily). To see what I mean, try `mutate(AlertTimeLocal = format(AlertTimeLocal, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `force_tzs` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(AlertTimeLocal = dmy_hm(AlertTime), 
           AlertTimeUTC = force_tzs(AlertTimeLocal, tzones = TimeZone))
# AlertTime            TimeZone      AlertTimeLocal        AlertTimeUTC
#1 11 May 2020, 06:22 PM      America/Denver 2020-05-11 18:22:00 2020-05-12 00:22:00
#2 11 MAY 2020, 04:11 AM America/Los_Angeles 2020-05-11 04:11:00 2020-05-11 11:11:00
#3 10 MAY 2020, 03:38 PM     America/Chicago 2020-05-10 15:38:00 2020-05-10 20:38:00
```

#### Update

If we need to store as separate time zones, we can use a `list` column

```
library(purrr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         mutate(AlertTime2 = dmy_hm(AlertTime), 
         AlertTimeUTC = force_tzs(AlertTime2, tzones = TimeZone), 
         AlertTimeLocal = map2(AlertTime2, TimeZone, ~ force_tz(.x, tzone = .y))) 


df2$AlertTimeLocal
#[[1]]
#[1] "2020-05-11 18:22:00 MDT"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2020-05-11 04:11:00 PDT"

#[[3]]
#[1] "2020-05-10 15:38:00 CDT"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(AlertTime = c("11 May 2020, 06:22 PM",
       "11 MAY 2020, 04:11 AM", 
"10 MAY 2020, 03:38 PM"), TimeZone = c("America/Denver", 
"America/Los_Angeles", 
"America/Chicago")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks, though your version without mutate seemed to work fine. also ```FreshAir$AlertTime_UTC <- force_tzs(dmy_hm(FreshAir$AlertTime), tzones = FreshAir$TimeZone) #Determine time in UTC
FreshAir$AlertTime_Local <- force_tzs(dmy_hm(FreshAir$AlertTime), tzones = "UTC") #Determine (formatted) time back in Local```

Comment: @Adam Yes, it should work.  I used `mutate` because it would be easier to extend the chain in case you. want to .

Answer (score 1):

I think a tidy solution might look cleaner, but if you want a base R solution, here's an alternative using @akrun's `df1`:

```r
df1$AlertTimeLocal <- df1$AlertTimeUTC <- 
  c.POSIXct(Map(as.POSIXct, df1$AlertTime, tz = df1$TimeZone, format = "%d %b %Y, %I:%M %p"))
attr(df1$AlertTimeUTC, "tzone") <- "UTC"
attr(df1$AlertTimeLocal, "tzone") <- "US/Mountain"
df1
#               AlertTime            TimeZone        AlertTimeUTC      AlertTimeLocal
# 1 11 May 2020, 06:22 PM      America/Denver 2020-05-12 00:22:00 2020-05-11 18:22:00
# 2 11 MAY 2020, 04:11 AM America/Los_Angeles 2020-05-11 11:11:00 2020-05-11 05:11:00
# 3 10 MAY 2020, 03:38 PM     America/Chicago 2020-05-10 20:38:00 2020-05-10 14:38:00
```

Something that has not been discussed, though: in R, you cannot have different time zones within one vector of `POSIXt`. That is, in a vector, time zone is an attribute of the *vector*, not of the element. If you need individual time zones for each time in that column, you'll need to do a list-column. This works but is not always supported well by utilities/functions that work on `data.frame`.

Comment: Because of the reference to `"MDT"` in the OP. It's just a placeholder, as much a reminder that the OP cannot (easily) get different timezones in each element of the column.

Comment: I don't know how better to say this: in a simple vector (column), R will not allow different time zones for individual elements. The attribute of `"tzone"` is applied to the vector as a whole. So the premise in the OP that each row can have a different local timezone is flawed (assuming a vector/column and not a list-column). Are you able to get different zones in your data?

Comment: I know that part.  But, I was curious why you selected the local as a specific one as I didn't find in the OP's post regarding that reference

Comment: It is right in the question: `AlertTimeLocal (desired)` in the header row, and `2020-05-11 18:22:00 MDT` in the next row. And then CDT and PDT. So I just used the first one, partly to illustrate my point.

Comment: yes, that was the first row,, but then it was CDT, so it was not clear